# Change a button to text button

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery script that uses a button right now. I want the 'button' to be a line of text that reads "More" instead of the input type of button.

Right now my button is

```
<input type="button" value="Show all" id="showAll" />
```

My jQuery is

```
$(window).ready( function() {
  $("#showAll").click(function () {
    $("#next40").slideDown(500);
    $(this).hide();
  });

  $("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#next40").slideUp(500, function () {
      $("#showAll").show();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, so what problem are you having?

Comment: do you want it to have the same id?

Comment: I am not sure how to do it. I have tried <a href="" value="Show all" id=showAll">More</a> but wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch your HTML to a span instead of an input and everything should work:

`<span id="showAll">More...</span>`

Comment: Thanks your code helped me out to develop this working answer. <a href="#" id="showAll">More</a>

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your input button in a `div` or other container, then use the jQuery `html()` function to replace that button with your text.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="toReplace">
    <input type="button" value="Show all" id="showAll" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#showAll").click(function () {
   $("#next40").slideDown(500);
   $(this).parent().html("More");
});
```

Comment: Did not work. Button is still there, and all it did was echo "More" into my text.

Comment: ? Yes that is how that works. Not what I explained in my question. I have a button, I want it to be text. Not click the button and change to text.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<div id="more">More</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('#more').click(function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

i guess this is what you require. here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L9CC8/1/) link

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the text of the button:

```
$("#showAll").attr("value","More");
```

and set it a class

```
$("#showAll").addClass("more");
```

and add some css to set a special style to the button, to show it as simple text

```
.more{
    border:0px;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of the following would do:

```
<a href="" id=showAll">More</a>
```

or

```
<span id=showAll">More</span >
```

and then:

```
$(window).ready( function() {

    $("#showAll").click(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault(); // this is required if you're using an anchor element: <a>

        $("#next40").slideDown(500);
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#hide").click(function () {
    $("#next40").slideUp(500, function () {
        $("#showAll").show();
    });

});
```

If you don't prevent the default event handler from executing (when using an anchor element), the page will refresh.

Answer (score -2):

You can use something like this:

```
$("#showAll").parent().append("<span>More</span>");
```